# Create a user form and extract certain data from the excel file via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

#### 1. About data

Initially, in the user form, I have 2 check boxes. The first one is User_Type (that contains 3 check boxes 1, 2, 3) and the second one is User_Size (that contains 4 check boxes S,M,L,XL). The master data sheet contains 5 columns: Type, Size, Quantity, Price_per_unit, Total_price. The "Type" column includes 1,2,3 and "Size" column includes "S", "M", "L", "XL".

#### 2. Expected output

How can I add to the below VBA code that works this way: If User_Type = Type and User_Size = Size, the relevant content of all 5 columns will be copied and pasted to another sheet?

#### 3. Example

| Type | Size | Quantity | Price_per_unit | Total_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S | 3 | 10 | 30 |
| 2 | M | 15 | 3 | 45 |
| 2 | S | 1 | 40 | 40 |
| 3 | L | 4 | 20 | 80 |
| 1 | XL | 7 | 5 | 35 |

For example, if I tick on the checkboxes 1 and 2 of User_Type and "S" of User_Size, the following information is supposed to be in another sheet:

| Type | Size | Quantity | Price_per_unit | Total_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S | 3 | 10 | 30 |
| 2 | S | 1 | 40 | 40 |

Furthermore, I also get stuck in creating a user form containing the checkboxes

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserInputForm.Show
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm ()
    'Fill TypeCheckBox
    With TypeListBox
        .AddItem "1"
        .AddItem "2"
        .AddItem "3"
    
    'Fill SizeCheckBox
    With SizeCheckBox
        .AddItem "S"
        .AddItem "M"
        .AddItem "L"
        .AddItem "XL"
    
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a command button in the UserForm and add this code on the click activity:

**Code inside UserInputForm:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call filtering
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'Fill TypeCheckBox
    With TypeListBox
        .AddItem "1"
        .AddItem "2"
        .AddItem "3"
    End With
    
    'Fill SizeCheckBox
    With SizeCheckBox
        .AddItem "S"
        .AddItem "M"
        .AddItem "L"
        .AddItem "XL"
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Then, this module will help you with the filtering and pasting in a different worksheet.

**Code for Module:**

```
Sub filtering()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim typeColumnNumber As Long, sizeColumnNumber As Long
    
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Update as needed
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 'Update as needed
    typeColumnNumber = 1 'Update as needed
    sizeColumnNumber = 2 'Update as needed
    
    Dim sizeFilter As String, typeFilter As String
    typeFilter = UserInputForm.TypeListBox.Value
    sizeFilter = UserInputForm.SizeCheckBox.Value
    
    Dim dataRange As Range, destinationRange As Range
    Set destinationRange = ws2.Range("A1") 'Update as needed
    Set dataRange = ws1.UsedRange
    
    'Clear filters
    If dataRange.AutoFilter Then dataRange.AutoFilter
    
    'Clear previous data
    ws2.UsedRange.ClearContents
    
    With dataRange
        .AutoFilter Field:=sizeColumnNumber, Criteria1:="=" & sizeFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=typeColumnNumber, Criteria1:="=" & typeFilter
        If .Columns(sizeColumnNumber).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
            .Copy
        Else
            GoTo exitpoint
        End If
    End With
    
    destinationRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    'Clear filters
    dataRange.AutoFilter
    
    Exit Sub
    
exitpoint:
    dataRange.AutoFilter
    MsgBox "No lines for selected criteria."
End Sub

Sub FormShow()
    UserInputForm.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I got an autofill error. It says autofilter method of range class fails

Comment: @Laura is your data in Sheet1 starting in Cell A1? The code I share will only work if the table starts in A1

Comment: Yes, my first row contains headers.

Comment: @Laura I updated my answer with updated code for both userform and module. Please give it a try and see if now works.

Answer (score 0):

So i started with following example list

[image]

and my userform looks like this

[image]

Code is not optimized so use at your own risk...

on change of the comboboxes the result list gets updated.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Call clearResults

    Call filterEntries
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    Call clearResults

    Call filterEntries
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With UserForm1.ComboBox1
        .AddItem "1"
        .AddItem "2"
        .AddItem "3"
    End With

    With UserForm1.ComboBox2
        .AddItem "S"
        .AddItem "M"
        .AddItem "L"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub clearResults()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F3:G7").Clear
End Sub

Private Sub filterEntries()
    Dim listOfEntries()
    Dim numOfEntries As Integer
    Dim numOfColumns As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    numOfColumns = 2

    numOfEntries = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    ReDim listOfEntries(numOfEntries, numOfColumns - 1)

    'get list of all entries
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Select
    For x = 1 To numOfEntries
        'get type into list
        listOfEntries(x - 1, 0) = CStr(ActiveCell)
        'get size into list
        listOfEntries(x - 1, 1) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
        
        ' Selects cell down 1 row from active cell to loop downwards
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next


    'filter and paste results
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F3").Select
    For x = 1 To numOfEntries
        If ComboBox1 = "" Or listOfEntries(x - 1, 0) = ComboBox1.Value Then
            If ComboBox2 = "" Or listOfEntries(x - 1, 1) = ComboBox2.Value Then
                Call pasteResult(x, listOfEntries)
            End If
        End If

        ' Selects cell down 1 row from active cell.
        If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub pasteResult(x As Integer, list As Variant)
    ActiveCell = list(x - 1, 0)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = list(x - 1, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: feel free to ask if you have any questions concerning my answer.

Comment: I got "Type mismatch" error :(